# Warning when installing npm using MacPorts I don't understand/what to do with?

Tags: macports, command-line, macos

I just installed `npm10` with MacPorts. At the end of the installation I got this warning:

```
It is not recommended to install packages globally. But if you do so please
be aware that they won't get cleaned up when you deactivate or uninstall
npm10. Globally installed packages will remain in
/opt/local/lib/node_modules/ until you manually delete them.
```

AFAIK, Everything I install using MacPorts is by default installed globally, and it is complicated or not possible to not install globally, isn't it?

What is the recommended "solution" to this warning? Couldn't find any documentation at MacPorts.

Answer (score 3):

> AFAIK, Everything I install using MacPorts is by default installed globally, and it is complicated or not possible to not install globally, isn't it?

By default, NPM packages are installed in the local NPM package's `node_modules` directory. You have to explicitly tell NPM to install packages globally, using `npm install --global`.

If you do this, then MacPorts doesn't know about those globally installed NPM packages, and thus it won't uninstall them when you uninstall NPM using MacPorts.

This warning is somewhat misleading since it explicitly mentions globally installed packages but obviously also applies to locally installed ones. After all, it would be extremely surprising if MacPorts were to randomly delete stuff from your ECMAScript projects!

It is also somewhat redundant, since it should be obvious that installing packages using a package manager other than MacPorts is not tracked by MacPorts – even if said package manager was itself installed by MacPorts.

> What is the recommended "solution" to this warning? Couldn't find any documentation at MacPorts.

It's not quite clear what you mean. The warning tells you what you have to do: if you want to completely remove NPM from the system, then you need to *both* uninstall all installed NPM packages using NPM *and* uninstall NPM using MacPorts (in that order, for obvious reasons). (Alternatively, you could just delete the entire `node_modules` directory manually, as suggested by the wanring).

If you want to know how to disable the warning, I am not familiar enough with MacPorts to answer that. There is probably a command line toggle, configuration file entry, or environment variable that can be set to suppress warnings. Then again, [maybe it is by design that warnings cannot be silenced](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/54388).

If you want to know what you could do instead of installing NPM and then installing NPM packages globally, then you could check whether the NPM package you want to install has been packaged as a MacPorts port, and if it hasn't, package it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. That explains a lot. My situation is that I want to install `prettier` to use with BBEdit's Script Menu. What is best practise for this? Should I make a local install in e.g., BBEdit's `Application Support` folder or should I make global installation in the default location in `/opt`?